# Troubles switching from VC++ Directories to User Macros for Boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, visual-studio-macros

Good day,

I have previously successfully used boost in Visual Studio 2010 by using Include and Library Directory paths under VC++ Directories in project settings. However not long ago I have been forced to switch to using "User Macros" to do the linking due to a new lecturer where I study.

I had no issues moving my other libraries to using User Macros, I simply used the same include and library path when creating the macros. Boost however is not playing so nice. While having the boost folder linked under VC++ Directories it worked as it should, but when I try moving the include and library paths to User Macros, Visual Studio refuses to recognize the path and I'm getting the following normal error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/filesystem.hpp': No such file or directory
```

When I move back to using VC++ Directories it works again.

Is there any simple explanation why boost doesn't want to be linked with macros, while all my other libs are totally fine with it? The other libraries include DevIL, SDL, glew, glm and assimp as of now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution. I had to add my boost macro names under "Project settings - C/C++ - Additional Include Directories" and "project settings - linker - Additional Library Directories".

Somehow the other macros I have made have appeared in those two lists automatically, and I'm not sure why the boost macros were not added automatically too. Now it's working as it should though, so I'll just go with it like this.